# Retrieve Single Object in Modelviewset

Tags: django-rest-framework

I was using CBV, ModelViewSet but somehow my API Keep showing all the Objects inside, how i get my ModelViewSet retrieve a single object that base on my sku ?

api/views.py

```
class SamAPIViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SamModels.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SamSerializers
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset

    def get_object(self):
        sku_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return self.get_queryset().filter(id=sku_id)

    def list(self, request):
        products = SamModels.objects.all()
        serializers = self.get_serializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializers.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializers = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializers.data)
```

api/urls.py

```
sam_api_list = SamAPIViewSet.as_view({
'get': 'list'
})

sam_api_detail = SamAPIViewSet.as_view({
'get': 'retrieve'
})

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'sam', sam_api_list, name='api-sam'),
    url(r'sam/<int:pk>', sam_api_detail, name='api-sam-detail'),
]
```

sam/1, it return all of my objects, i am not sure what wrong, my object has name, id, sku and how do i change my view to get retrieve single object base on my sku and not my id ?

Answer (score 2):

```
url(r'sam/<int:pk>', sam_api_detail, name='api-sam-detail'),
url(r'sam', sam_api_list, name='api-sam'),
```

to

```
path(r'sam/<str:pk>', sam_api_detail, name='api-sam-detail'),
path(r'sam', sam_api_list, name='api-sam'),
```

remove

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset

    def get_object(self):
        sku_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return self.get_queryset().filter(id=sku_id)
```

and change lookup_field = 'pk' to lookup_field = 'sku'

Answer (score 1):

Your routes are upside down. Try this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'sam/<int:pk>', sam_api_detail, name='api-sam-detail'),
    url(r'sam', sam_api_list, name='api-sam'),
]
```

Django will select the first expression that matches. If r'sam' is above r'sam/int:pk' then it will select r'sam' without going down to the next entry

Comment: but i hook them and make them go directly to that function.

Comment: @user8566930 It doesn't matter. If your first regular expression matches, Django will not read any further into the file

Comment: Understood, that really explain why i keep getting all objects, one more question, how do i make the retrieve search for object sku instead of id ?

Comment: @user8566930 return self.get_queryset().filter(id=sku_id) change id=sku_id to sku=sku_id and in url(r'sam/<int:pk>', sam_api_detail, name='api-sam-detail'), change <int:pk> to <str:sku>

Comment: thanks mate ! i will get it a try, hopefully get the single object, appreicate your help mate

Comment: @user8566930 If your original question has been resolved, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Oh i tested, it didt work, i put the url on top of it.

Comment: i change the url into path and use lookup_field to help me search for sku, that work fine :D