# How to create a ModelViewset when model has OneToOneField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The idea is to have a model like this:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and then create a serializer and a **ModelViewSet** related to it.

The problem is that ModelViewSet must return a queryset but I want to work with single objects due to the one-to-one relation.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset):

> The `ModelViewSet` class inherits from `GenericAPIView` and includes implementations for various actions, by mixing in the behavior of the various mixin classes.

This means that `ModelViewSet` also takes care of situation where a specific `Object` should be returned. You can even override `def get_object(self)` if you want a behavior more complex than what is implemented (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892493/retrieve-single-object-in-modelviewset)).

However, to really ensure that only one `Object` is returned, I would advice you to use a field as a unique primary key. You would populate this field on insertion (manually or [automatically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)) and then use it as a `lookup_field`.

Below, I assumed that you already had a `__str__(self)` function in your `User` model as well.

Then, your `Object` model would become:

```py
class Object(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)  # or another unique primary_key field 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self.id})"
```

Your serializer would be:

```py
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ("id", "name", "user")

    id = serializers.CharField(required=True)
```

Your `ModelViewSet` would be something like:

```
class ObjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ["get"]
    # parser_classes = [JSONParser] # Replace with your parser class
    queryset = Object.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    lookup_field = "id"
```

Finally, to make the whole thing works you would also have to register your `ModelViewSet` in your `urlpatterns`.

I use to explicitly bind my `ViewSet` classes into a set of concrete views but this is more of a personal choice so it's up to you. You can check the corresponding [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/) for more info.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path(
        r"objects/<str:id>",
        ObjectViewSet.as_view({"get": "retrieve"}),
    ),
    ...
]
```

With all this, a request to `<BASE_URL>/objects/<YOUR_OBJECT_ID>` should return only one `Object` result.